# polarized cross section vs. unpolarized one?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

Could someone explain to me the difference between polarized and unpolarized cross section with an example? I'm studying Peskin chapter 5, and I'm not sure what he means by polarized cross section.

Answer (score 1):

Unpolarized cross section is a sum over all spin combinations (polarizations) of polarized cross sections.